One Windows 10 computer, two network adapters, set NDI on local network
The goal is to get an NDI video feed from OBS out to a Magewell NDI decoder  using the onboard ethernet adapter. The reason I'd like to do this is to segregate the video data from the internet data for more efficient bandwidth.
I have two ethernet adapters. I'd like one of those adapters to be connected to the internet. The other adapter I'd like to be used to send the OBS NDI feed over to the decoder. What should my setup look like in detail? Please help by providing recommended settings and steps.
Note that my setup works with no problem if the decoder and computer are connected to the same network through a switch connected to the internet. This is less desirable as I don't want the internet data to interfere with the necessary bandwidth for video. The more desirable setup is that the decoder is directly connected to one of the computer's ethernet adapters, specifically configured to send NDI video data from OBS.
Note that the decoder does have a local IP address used to access the admin settings using a web browser. Let's say that IP address is 192.168.4.4. Ideally, I'd like to be able to access the admin panel with the setup.
